# Creating list bundles from Infinite Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a method `Observable<SensorEvent> dataFromSensor()` which returns infinite stream of `SensorEvents`.
I need to collect them into lists with 20 sensor events.
How I can get this?
`buffer(20)` doesn't work, it returns Lists with 20 items but every item in this list is the same.

More code:

With `RxSensors`

```
final RxSensorManager sensorManager = new RxSensorManager(oldSensorManager);
sensorManager.observeSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
.buffer(20)
.onSubscribe( /*onNext, onError, onCompleted omitted*/)
```

but there is no difference if I create it with `Observable.fromAsync()` and sensorManager callback or `RxSensors`. Every list in `onSubscribe` have this same items.

Comment: please provide your code. buffer should work fine maybe is in some other place. or items is really same

Comment: added more code @PogonetsAnton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `SensorManager` change same SensorEvent each time.
Try to add same clone like stuff before buffer.

For example:

```
    sensorManager.observeSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
            .map(sensorEvent -> {
                List<Float> copy = new ArrayList<>();

                for (float value : sensorEvent.values) {
                    copy.add(value);
                }

                return copy;
            })
            .buffer(20)
            .subscribe();
```